# Adding directory to 7z archive

Tags: 7zip

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
SomeDir/
    Subdir1/
    Subdir2/
    Subdir3/
```

each subdir contains a lot of stuff so to compress/extract `Somedir` takes a long time. I want to compress each `Subdir` seperately, but I need each archive to contain the path

```
Somedir/SubdirN/contents_of_SubdirN  # for N in [1, 2, 3]
```

At the moment I am compressing `SomeDir` then copying it 3 times, and for each archive, removing 2 of the `Subdirs`. But I feel like there is a better way.

Is there some way I can either compress `SubdirN` by itself, then add `Somedir` to the root of the archive, and move `SubdirN` into `Somedir`, or compress `SubdirN` specifying that it should be compressed into a directory called `Somedir`?

Or possibly some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I was unable to find on option for 7zip to do this. I ended up writing a python script that copied what I wanted archived to another location in the hierarchy I wanted, then calling 7zip on the directory.